# Control stuck inside an infinite loop because of checkbox events in Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid in WPF with first column as a checkbox. I have now added a select all checkbox which appears on the header of the column that it is bound to.
The handlers for the select all checkbox and individual row check boxes are defined as:

```
    private void SelectAllCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (BaseDataItem objItem in BaseReleaseList)
        {
            objItem.Select = true;
        }
        BaseReleaseDataGridView.Items.Refresh();
    }

    private void SelectAllCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (BaseDataItem objItem in BaseReleaseList)
        {
            objItem.Select = false;
        }
        BaseReleaseDataGridView.Items.Refresh();
    }


    private void RowCheckBoxUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectAllCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
    }

    private void RowCheckBoxChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AreAllCheckBoxesChecked())
            SelectAllCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        else
            SelectAllCheckBox.IsChecked = false;

        BaseReleaseDataGridView.Items.Refresh();
    }


    private bool AreAllCheckBoxesChecked()
    {
        foreach (BaseDataItem objItem in BaseReleaseList)
        {
            if (!objItem.Select)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now the problem is that whenever i click on the select all checkbox or the row check box, control gets stuck inside an infinite loop. Reason is that whenever i set, select to true or false, it again fires an event. How can this be handled.

Comment: No, the idea is to NOT fire that loop for rows selection changed. I'd use `RoutedEventArgs.Source` (or any similar) to check whether it was the row firing the event or the header.

Comment: Welcome to the world of poor implementation! If you stay there, you'd better get used to these kinds of problems. If, on the other hand, you were to use WPF correctly (using data binding) then you wouldn't have any of these problems because you would only have to set the `bool` properties that were data bound to the `Checkbox`es to `true`: `foreach (Item item in Items) item.BoolProperty = true;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of tapping two events `Checked` and `UnChecked`, register to `Click` event. Click event will be raised on when user clicks on the checkbox unlike Checked/UnChecked which get called even when you check/uncheck your checkbox programatically.

```
 <CheckBox Name="SelectAllCheckBox" Click="SelectAll_OnClick"></CheckBox>
```

in handler

```
    private void SelectAll_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool? isChecked = SelectAllCheckBox.IsChecked;
        if (isChecked.HasValue)
        {
            foreach (BaseDataItem objItem in BaseReleaseList)
            {
                objItem.Select = isChecked;
            }
            BaseReleaseDataGridView.Items.Refresh();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Click event wont be called when you check/uncheck your checkbox programatically. it will only be called when user click on the checkbox

Comment: was this question in continuation of your previous question? showing checkbox in header?